# Double y-axis on left and right side of plot in Makie.jl

Tags: plot, julia

I want to make a double yaxis in Makie, so that one y axis on the left and has its own values, and the other is on the right and has its own values, while they share x axis.

For example to do this in PyPlot one would follow https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html and get

[image]

How is this done in Makie.jl? If the answer could say how to also color the axis, then double points from me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With CairoMakie 0.3.7, AbstractPlotting 0.13.8:

```
using CairoMakie
using CairoMakie.AbstractPlotting.MakieLayout

scene, layout = layoutscene(resolution = (600, 400))
ax1 = layout[1, 1] = LAxis(scene, yticklabelcolor = :blue, ytickcolor = :blue)
ax2 = layout[1, 1] = LAxis(scene, yticklabelcolor = :red, ytickcolor = :red, backgroundcolor = :transparent)

hidexdecorations!(ax2)
hidespines!(ax2)
yaxis_right!(ax2)
linkxaxes!(ax1, ax2)

lines!(ax1, 0..10, sin, color = :blue)
lines!(ax2, 0..10, x -> 5cos(x), color = :red)

scene
```

[image: example]

Comment: Docs for this: https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/examples/layoutables/axis/#creating_a_twin_axis

Comment: The doc link shared by rashid doesn't seem to work. @julesmules how would you put the two y axis say on the left side?

Comment: Late to the party; but the current link seems to be https://docs.makie.org/stable/examples/blocks/axis/index.html#creating_a_twin_axis